# Find a value by substring in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, rss, atom-feed

Just to give my problem a context: I am writing a Django webapp that includes several applications. One of them is used to display articles from RSS feeds. For now, I was only displaying the link, source and description. I want to add thumbnails to these articles. 
I'm trying to grab these thumbnails for **any** RSS or ATOM feed. Theses feeds are for some parts (e.g. images) constructed in totally arbitrary ways. Since I don't want to write a specific script for every feed on the Web, my idea is to look for ".jpg", ".png" substrings in every article I fetch and get that URL.
Getting from RSS or ATOM feeds to articles is well handled by the python Feedparser module, and outputs this for example:

```
 {'guidislink': False,
  'href': '',
  'id': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/39426760',
  'link': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/39426760',
  'links': [{'href': 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/39426760',
             'rel': 'alternate',
             'type': 'text/html'}],
  'media_thumbnail': [{'height': '576',
                       'url': 'http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/44A9/production/_95477571_joshking2.jpg',
                       'width': '1024'}],
  'published': 'Wed, 05 Apr 2017 21:49:14 GMT',
  'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=21, tm_min=49, tm_sec=14, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=95, tm_isdst=0),
  'summary': 'Joshua King scores a dramatic late equaliser for Bournemouth as '
             'Liverpool drop two crucial points at Anfield.',
  'summary_detail': {'base': 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',
                     'language': None,
                     'type': 'text/html',
                     'value': 'Joshua King scores a dramatic late equaliser '
                              'for Bournemouth as Liverpool drop two crucial '
                              'points at Anfield.'},
  'title': 'Liverpool 2-2 Bournemouth',
  'title_detail': {'base': 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml',
                   'language': None,
                   'type': 'text/plain',
                   'value': 'Liverpool 2-2 Bournemouth'}}
```

Here, `http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/44A9/production/_95477571_joshking2.jpg` is somewhere nested in lists and dictionaries. While I know how to access it in this specific case, the structures of feeds widely vary. Mainly:

- The dictionary key holding the url is not always the same
- The 'deepness' of where the url might be nested is not always the same

However, what is almost always the case is that an url with an image extension is the thumbnail of that article. How do I get that url?

To frame it out a little more, for now I use helper functions (based on the Feedparser module) that processes a `feeds` context variable, which is a dictionary, usable in my templates. I do the looping and displaying of title, description etc directly in my templates, since they are consistently a part of that dictionary thanks to feedparser:

```
...
{% for feed in feeds %}
  <h3>{{ feed.feed.title }}</h3>
  {% for entry in feed.entries %}
...
```

On the backend :

```
def parse_feeds(urls):
    parsed_feeds = []
    for url in urls:
        parsed_feed = feedparser.parse(url)
        parsed_feeds.append(parsed_feed)
    return parsed_feeds

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'publisher/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        reacted_feeds = RSSArticle.objects.all()
        context['reacted_feeds'] = reacted_feeds
        parsed_feeds = parse_feeds(urls)
        delete_existing_entries(parsed_feeds)
        context['feeds'] = parsed_feeds
        return context
```

So basically every time you call that IndexView, you get the list of all articles from the feeds you subscribed to. That's where I want to include the image, which are not provided by Feedparser due to the inconsistent nature of their location in feeds.

If I want to include these pictures, at a macro level I basically have two solutions:

- Writing something in addition to the existing system, but that might hurt performance because of too many things having to happen at the same time
- Rewriting the whole thing, which might also hurt performance and consistency because I don't take advantage of Feedparser's power anymore

Maybe I should just keep the raw XML and try my luck with Beautifulsoup instead of translating to a dictionary with Feedparser.

PS : here is another example where the image is located somewhere else.

```
{'guidislink': False,
 'id': 'http://www.lemonde.fr/tiny/5106451/',
 'link': 'http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2017/04/05/presidentielle-les-grands-clivages-qui-divisent-les-onze-candidats_5106451_4355770.html?xtor=RSS-3208',
 'links': [{'href': 'http://www.lemonde.fr/les-decodeurs/article/2017/04/05/presidentielle-les-grands-clivages-qui-divisent-les-onze-candidats_5106451_4355770.html?xtor=RSS-3208',
            'rel': 'alternate',
            'type': 'text/html'},
           {'href': 'http://s1.lemde.fr/image/2017/04/05/644x322/5106578_3_0f2b_sur-le-plateau-du-debat-de-bfmtv-et-cnews_0e90a3db44861847870cfa1e4c3793b1.jpg',
            'length': '40057',
            'rel': 'enclosure',
            'type': 'image/jpeg'}],
 'published': 'Wed, 05 Apr 2017 17:02:38 +0200',
 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=5, tm_hour=15, tm_min=2, tm_sec=38, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=95, tm_isdst=0),
 'summary': 'Protection sociale, Europe, identité… Avec leurs programmes, les '
            'proximités idéologiques entre candidats bousculent de plus en '
            'plus le traditionnel axe «\xa0gauche-droite\xa0».',
 'summary_detail': {'base': 'http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml',
                    'language': None,
                    'type': 'text/html',
                    'value': 'Protection sociale, Europe, identité… Avec leurs '
                             'programmes, les proximités idéologiques entre '
                             'candidats bousculent de plus en plus le '
                             'traditionnel axe «\xa0gauche-droite\xa0».'},
 'title': 'Présidentielle\xa0: les grands clivages qui divisent les onze '
          'candidats',
 'title_detail': {'base': 'http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml',
                  'language': None,
                  'type': 'text/plain',
                  'value': 'Présidentielle\xa0: les grands clivages qui '
                           'divisent les onze candidats'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a solution based on [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/PierreMonico/starred).

```
def get_image_url(substring, dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        # try is for handling Booleans
        try:
            if substring in value:
                yield value
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                for result in get_image_url(substring, value):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                for list_item in value:
                    for result in get_image_url(substring, list_item):
                        yield result
        except:
            pass

>>> list(get_image_url('.jpg', article_dict))
>>> ['https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/04/09/us/10OBAMA-alt/10OBAMA-alt-moth.jpg']
```

PS : while it does not answer the exact question of finding a value in a nested dictionary, I found out that a good way to get images for articles from RSS feeds in a consistent manner is simply to follow back the URL to the original article, parse the HTML and search for the `og:image` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the thumbnail, I would think that the easy way would be to ignore everything else, and simply search every value string for the desired tail.  There are plenty of links to help you traverse the structure, should you care to do that, but I'd turn it into a string and then parse that.

Your trigger is a colon followed by white-space and a quotation mark.  Grab what's between the quotation marks.  Call that **value**

```
extensions = [".jpg", ".png"]
...
if value[-4:] in extensions:
    # You've found a desired URL
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I thought of that, and it might help. The problem is I need more than the image and I need it for hundreds of articles at page load time (webapp), so it might hurt performance. I'll try it anyway, thanks!

Comment: If you need more, then search SO for how to recursively descend through dictionaries.  You can still use the extension matching on **present_dict.values** to spot the critical fields.

Comment: Note, however, that we can't really write code for you, since (1) we don't do end-to-end coding tasks; (2) it seems that you haven't defined your entire problem; (3) you haven't provided a framework of code under which we can solve a specific problem.  Pick the range of what you need solved, give us your best shot, and we'll see about filling in one or two holes for you.

Comment: I made edits; hope it's clearer now. Thanks for pointing out additional searches I can carry out.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that my first comment was unclear as well. What I meant by "I need more than the image" is "I have already implemented code to get everything else than the image, and using solution to get the images that doesn't fit the existing implementation might hurt performance".